# how to upload doc/img using multipartFormData with nested parameter?

Tags: json, objective-c, swift, xcode, alamofire

I want to achieve the following parameter structure in my Almofire request

```
{
  "usr_data": token,
  "StudentLeaveDataList": [
    {
      "stulv_Description": "test",
      "stulv_Reason": "2nd leave",
      "stulv_fromdate": "19-Jun-2020",
      "stulv_id": "0",
      "stulv_todate": "20-Jun-2020",
      "stuv_file": (data_File),
      "stuv_filename": "abc.pdf",
      "stuv_lvtpid": "8"
    }
  ]
}
```

using Alamofire multipart data method